# How to improve performance while calculating matrix sum

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I was given a task during an interview, where I was given a matrix, now I need to generate another matrix out of it using below formula:

Given matrix A[R][C], generate B[R][C]

```
val = 0;
for (i = 0; i ≤ xPosition; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j ≤ yPosition; j += 1) {
        val = val + a(i, j);
    }
}

B(xPosition,yPosition) = val;
```

I have come up with below code:

```
public List<List<Integer>> generate(List<List<Integer>> A) {
        List<List<Integer>> top = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < A.get(0).size(); j++) {
                inner.add(generateValue(A, i, j));
            }
            top.add(inner);
        }
        return top;
    }

    int generateValue(List<List<Integer>> A, int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= xPosition; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= yPosition; j++) {
                int value = A.get(i).get(j);
                val += value;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

**Sample input :**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

**Output :**

```
1 3 6
5 12 21
```

How to improve the performance of this logic?

Comment: Hi! I think your question is off-topic here, but on topic on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Did you send in your code? What would the company, that is considering hiring you, think about you asking for help?

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti, this was asked some days back, I just wanted to know where I made mistake in solving this simple logic.

Comment: recalculating for each element value

Answer (score 3):

mathematicaly for your solution in array b,each element is related to it's previous one.

to improve your code / optimise it you need to see this relation. 
so for every B[i][j] is related to it's previous element and value from the array A.

below is solution mathematically,

```
b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] + a[i][0]+a[i][1] + a[i][2]+...+a[i][y-1]
```

for so if you able to implement this, your code will pass all test cases

i am not a java dev, but if you want code, i can write it for you in python

Answer (score 1):

The key is to think of this as a dynamic programming problem, assuming that we have already calculated `B[x][y]` for all `0 <= x < i`, `0 <= y < j` when we go to calculate `B[i][j]`.

`B[i][j]` contains the sum of all elements in the submatrix of `A` that starts at `0, 0` and ends at `i, j`. Thus `B[i-1][j]` will contain the sum of the all the elements in this submatrix *except* the ones in the `i`th row. Similarly, `B[i][j-1]` will contain the sum of the all the elements in this submatrix *except* the ones in the `j`th column. Adding these two together, we get the sum of all the elements in the submatrix except for element `A[i][j]`. However, while doing this we count all the elements from `0, 0` to `i-1, j-1` twice, and we have to subtract their sum (which is `B[i-1][j-1]`) once so that we only sum them up once in total. Then we add the missing element, `A[i][j]`. Hence

```
B[i][j] = B[i-1][j] + B[i][j-1] - B[i-1][j-1] + A[i][j]
```

This recursion can now be implemented as a `O(RC)` dynamic programming algorithm.

To help understand this further, consider the following figure representing the submatrix for which we have to find the sum of the elements. The figure is a matrix `C[i][j]`, where the `x, y`th element is the number of times we have summed `A[x][y]`. In terms of `C[i][j]`, our end goal (`B[i][j]`) is

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

`B[i-1][j]` corresponds to the matrix `C[i-1][j]`, which is

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

`B[i][j-1]` corresponds to the matrix `C[i][j-1]`, which is

```
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
```

`B[i-1][j] + B[i][j-1]` corresponds to the matrix `C[i-1][j] + C[i][j-1]`, which is

```
2 2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

`B[i-1][j] + B[i][j-1] - B[i-1][j-1]` corresponds to the matrix `C[i-1][j] + C[i][j-1] - C[i-1][j-1]`, which is

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

Now `B[i-1][j] + B[i][j-1] - B[i-1][j-1] + A[i][j]` corresponds to

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

which is the same as `B[i][j]`.